# How can I vectorize a function to two take as arguments two sequences of different lengths (m and n) and return a matrix (m x n) in Python NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, vectorization

I have to sequences (for example) and a function:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10,21)
b = np.arange(10,16)

def f(x,y):
    return x**2+y*3
```

and I want to construct a matrix (10x5), so that each one of its elements will be the result of the function on these elements iteratively. So, for example, the element of the **2nd** row and **3rd** column of the matrix will be:

```
matrix[1,2]
>>> 157
```

namely f(11,12) = 11**2 + 12*3 = 121 + 36 = 157.

I tried with nested loops (two "for" loops), but it is too slow. Is there a way for numpy to perform the operations at once, for example an np function that takes as argument `a`, `b` and `f` and returns the desired result?

Many thanks :)

Comment: `def f(x,y):
    return x[:,None]**2+y*3`?

Comment: If `x` is a (m,1) array, and `y` is (n,) shape, operations like add and multiply will create a (m,n) array.  The (n,) is expanded to (1,n) automatically.  This is called `broadcasting`.

Comment: Don't you want a 11x6 matrix? Or maybe change the bounds of your arange()

Answer (score 0):

You can make `a` into a column vector and voilà :

```
matrix = a[:,np.newaxis] ** 2 + b * 3
```

Though something like this is cleaner:

```
a, b = np.ogrid[10:21,10:16]
matrix = a ** 2 + b * 3
```

(edited thanks to hpaulj's comment)

Comment: `a[:,None]` is perhaps the most common and idiomatic way of turning a (m,) shape into a (m,1).   It (and `reshape`) makes a `view`.  `np.c_` makes a copy.

Comment: Good point! I have also seen `np.expand_dims`, is this also a good option?